ConversationParticipant bizarre behavior
Anybody else notice that:

ConversationParticipant doesn't attempt to populate the ParticipantEntityId field until the ConversationParticipant record is SELECTed
The first point is only valid if you are not the Automated Process user (which the AWS Contact Center utilizes, womp womp)

I have a trigger that selects [SELECT Id, ParticipantEntityId FROM ConversationParticipant WHERE Id IN :var] which returns only the Id when run via Trigger as Automated Process. However, when I go into Console and put in the exact same SELECT query, it comes back with a ParticipantEntityId AND LastModifiedDate == NOW AND LastModifiedById == ME... it's clearly running this on SELECT/view, but does Automated Process somehow not have the same authority/access?
